# Counting conccurent user sessions by time intervals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intervals

My data is made up of sessions with start and end timestamps. My task is to count the number of sessions by company and app version that are 'active' for each interval. I'm starting with an interval of 30 minutes. Thus if a Company has a session that lasts from 2:10pm to 3:35pm... that Company would count in each of the 4 bins/intervals (2:00, 2:30, 3:00, 3:30). How would I go about solving this in spark/scala?

Ultimately, I'll need this to scale for millions of sessions daily.

This is my sample data:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List( ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-02T01:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:29:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:17:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-01T23:53:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:29:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-01T22:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-01T23:41:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:29:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:17:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:41:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:17:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-02T00:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:05:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T23:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:53:00.000+0000"), ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:41:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T23:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:05:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-02T00:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:53:00.000+0000"), ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:05:00.000+0000")  )).toDF("customer","device_model","start_timestamp","end_timestamp")
.withColumn("start_timestamp", to_timestamp($"start_timestamp"))
.withColumn("end_timestamp", to_timestamp($"end_timestamp"))
display(df)
```

I'd like my results to appear as below. These counts are at 30min intervals, but ultimately I'll be counting as low as one or two minute intervals.

```
timeinterval           customer  xi1 xi2
2020-07-01 22:30:00  Company A   1   1
2020-07-01 22:30:00  Company B   0   1
2020-07-01 23:00:00  Company A   1   2
2020-07-01 23:00:00  Company B   1   1
2020-07-01 23:30:00  Company A   1   4
2020-07-01 23:30:00  Company B   2   1
2020-07-02 00:00:00  Company A   1   4
2020-07-02 00:00:00  Company B   3   1
2020-07-02 00:30:00  Company A   2   4
2020-07-02 00:30:00  Company B   3   1
2020-07-02 01:00:00  Company A   2   3
2020-07-02 01:00:00  Company B   2   2
2020-07-02 01:30:00  Company A   2   1
2020-07-02 01:30:00  Company B   2   2
2020-07-02 02:00:00  Company A   0   1
2020-07-02 02:00:00  Company B   1   2
2020-07-02 02:30:00  Company B   1   1
```

Any help or thoughts on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is helpful-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
      ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-02T01:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:29:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:17:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-01T23:53:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:29:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-01T22:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-01T23:41:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:07:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:29:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:17:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi1", "2020-07-02T00:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:41:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:55:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:17:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi2", "2020-07-02T00:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T02:05:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T23:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:53:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company B","xi1", "2020-07-01T23:19:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:41:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T23:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:05:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-02T00:31:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T01:53:00.000+0000"),
      ("Company A","xi2", "2020-07-01T22:43:00.000+0000", "2020-07-02T00:05:00.000+0000")  ))
      .toDF("customer","device_model","start_timestamp","end_timestamp")
      .withColumn("start_timestamp", to_timestamp($"start_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
      .withColumn("end_timestamp", to_timestamp($"end_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |customer |device_model|start_timestamp    |end_timestamp      |
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:37:00|2020-07-02 07:59:00|
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:25:00|2020-07-02 06:47:00|
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:01:00|2020-07-02 05:23:00|
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 04:37:00|2020-07-02 05:59:00|
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 03:49:00|2020-07-02 05:11:00|
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:37:00|2020-07-02 06:59:00|
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 06:25:00|2020-07-02 07:47:00|
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:49:00|2020-07-02 07:11:00|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:25:00|2020-07-02 05:47:00|
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:13:00|2020-07-02 07:35:00|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 05:01:00|2020-07-02 06:23:00|
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 04:49:00|2020-07-02 06:11:00|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 05:13:00|2020-07-02 06:35:00|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:01:00|2020-07-02 07:23:00|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:13:00|2020-07-02 05:35:00|
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

### **`sequence + interval`** to generate bins/intervals

> change intervalInMinutes as required

```scala
    val intervalInMinutes = 30
    val seconds = intervalInMinutes * 60 // seconds
    val p = df.withColumn("new_start", to_timestamp(floor($"start_timestamp".cast("long")/ seconds ) * seconds))
      .withColumn("splits", sequence(
      $"new_start",
      $"end_timestamp",
      expr(s"interval $intervalInMinutes MINUTE")))
    p.show(false)

    /**
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |customer |device_model|start_timestamp    |end_timestamp      |new_start          |splits                                                                              |
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:37:00|2020-07-02 07:59:00|2020-07-02 06:30:00|[2020-07-02 06:30:00, 2020-07-02 07:00:00, 2020-07-02 07:30:00]                     |
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:25:00|2020-07-02 06:47:00|2020-07-02 05:00:00|[2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00]|
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:01:00|2020-07-02 05:23:00|2020-07-02 04:00:00|[2020-07-02 04:00:00, 2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00]                     |
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 04:37:00|2020-07-02 05:59:00|2020-07-02 04:30:00|[2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00]                     |
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 03:49:00|2020-07-02 05:11:00|2020-07-02 03:30:00|[2020-07-02 03:30:00, 2020-07-02 04:00:00, 2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00]|
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:37:00|2020-07-02 06:59:00|2020-07-02 05:30:00|[2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00]                     |
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 06:25:00|2020-07-02 07:47:00|2020-07-02 06:00:00|[2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00, 2020-07-02 07:00:00, 2020-07-02 07:30:00]|
      * |Company A|xi1         |2020-07-02 05:49:00|2020-07-02 07:11:00|2020-07-02 05:30:00|[2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00, 2020-07-02 07:00:00]|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:25:00|2020-07-02 05:47:00|2020-07-02 04:00:00|[2020-07-02 04:00:00, 2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00]|
      * |Company B|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:13:00|2020-07-02 07:35:00|2020-07-02 06:00:00|[2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00, 2020-07-02 07:00:00, 2020-07-02 07:30:00]|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 05:01:00|2020-07-02 06:23:00|2020-07-02 05:00:00|[2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00]                     |
      * |Company B|xi1         |2020-07-02 04:49:00|2020-07-02 06:11:00|2020-07-02 04:30:00|[2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00]|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 05:13:00|2020-07-02 06:35:00|2020-07-02 05:00:00|[2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00, 2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00]|
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 06:01:00|2020-07-02 07:23:00|2020-07-02 06:00:00|[2020-07-02 06:00:00, 2020-07-02 06:30:00, 2020-07-02 07:00:00]                     |
      * |Company A|xi2         |2020-07-02 04:13:00|2020-07-02 05:35:00|2020-07-02 04:00:00|[2020-07-02 04:00:00, 2020-07-02 04:30:00, 2020-07-02 05:00:00, 2020-07-02 05:30:00]|
      * +---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      */
```

### **`pivot+count`** to get the counts per interval

```scala
    p.select($"customer", $"device_model", explode($"splits").as("timeinterval"))
      .groupBy("timeinterval", "customer")
      .pivot("device_model")
      .agg(
        count("device_model")
      )
      .withColumn("xi1", coalesce($"xi1", lit(0)))
      .withColumn("xi2", coalesce($"xi2", lit(0)))
      .orderBy("timeinterval", "customer")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------------------+---------+---+---+
      * |timeinterval       |customer |xi1|xi2|
      * +-------------------+---------+---+---+
      * |2020-07-02 03:30:00|Company A|1  |0  |
      * |2020-07-02 04:00:00|Company A|1  |2  |
      * |2020-07-02 04:00:00|Company B|0  |1  |
      * |2020-07-02 04:30:00|Company A|1  |2  |
      * |2020-07-02 04:30:00|Company B|2  |1  |
      * |2020-07-02 05:00:00|Company A|2  |4  |
      * |2020-07-02 05:00:00|Company B|2  |1  |
      * |2020-07-02 05:30:00|Company A|2  |4  |
      * |2020-07-02 05:30:00|Company B|3  |0  |
      * |2020-07-02 06:00:00|Company A|2  |3  |
      * |2020-07-02 06:00:00|Company B|3  |1  |
      * |2020-07-02 06:30:00|Company A|2  |2  |
      * |2020-07-02 06:30:00|Company B|2  |2  |
      * |2020-07-02 07:00:00|Company A|1  |1  |
      * |2020-07-02 07:00:00|Company B|1  |2  |
      * |2020-07-02 07:30:00|Company B|1  |2  |
      * +-------------------+---------+---+---+
      */
```